# MultiBinding to an ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

I am working with wpf and multibinding to a list of ViewModel.

Suppose I have an ObservableCollection of the same kind of ViewModel as follows:

Code:

```
public class ShapeVM
{

    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}


ObservableCollection ShapeVMs = new ObservableCollection();
ShapeVMs.Add(...);
ShapeVMs.Add(...);
ShapeVMs.Add(...);
ShapeVMs.Add(...);
ShapeVMs.Add(...);
// There are 5 ShapeVM in the collection.
```

View:

```
<UserControl .........>

    <ColorBox SelectedColor="{Binding Path=Color, Mode=TwoWay}" />

</UserControl>
```

Is it possible that whenever the SelectedColor of the ColorBox is changed, the Color of the 5 ShapeVMs will be automatically changed to the SelectedColor of the ColorBox at the same time?

if I set the DataContext of the UserControl to be either one ShapeVM, then the Color of only either one ShapeVM will be changed.

However, I would like to change the 5 ShapeVMs at the same time the SelectedColor of the ColorBox changed. How could I do so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple Solution to your problem is

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ShapeVMs}" DisplayMemberPath="Color" Height="40" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedColor,ElementName=clrbox}" SelectedValuePath="Color"/>
    <ColorBox x:Name="clrbox"/>
```

I hope this one will help.

Comment: It can only update one item (SelectedItem) in the ComboBox? But what I want is to update all the ShapeVM in the ComboBox whenever the SelectedColor is changed in the ColorBox. How could I do so? Thanks.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the problem, I think in the set of your Color property you can set All color of your collection to value using loop or you can write the Converter but the logic is same, so its better you set the selectedColor in the setter of your Color Property that you are binding to SelectedColor

Comment: I have updated the above solution though Instead of ColorBox I have used TextBox and PhoneNumber instead of ShapeVM . But the logic is kind of that written in the setter of SelectedItemName property.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the VM's Color property to your ColorBox:

1. Derive ShapeVM from DependencyObject
2. Let Color be a dependency property
3. Give ColorBox a name (x:Name="TheColorBox")
4. For every ShapeVM you instantiate, create a binding in code-behind:

   Binding binding = new Binding();
   inding.source = TheColorBox;
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath(ColorBox.SelectedColorProperty);
   shapeVM.SetBinding(ShapeVM.ColorProperty, binding);

(for some reason code markup doesn't work, sorry)